# How to round in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, undefined

I am using toFixed() function to round numbers to two decimal places such that this number

```
94.3107 becomes 94.31.
```

But when I do this it gives me undefined. This is my code :

```
    controller: function($scope, $rootScope, KpiChartFactory) {



            $scope.$watch('selectedP', function() {
                    console.log($scope.selectedP);
                    console.log("ChangedP");
                    ChartData();    
                    $scope.DataCallback({
                        selectedP : $scope.pUnitDefault
                        });

                }, true);

            $scope.$watch('selectedK', function() {
                console.log($scope.selectedK);
                console.log("ChangedSelected");
                ChartData();    
                $scope.DataCallback({
                    selectedK : $scope.kDefault
                    });

            }, true);


            $scope.$watch('selectedK', function(){
                console.log("ChangedParams");
                ChartData();
            },true);



          function getValue(selectedK) {
              for(var i= 0; i< $scope.selectedK.length;i++){
                  $scope.selectedK[i] = selectedK[i].toFixed(2);
                  console.log($scope.selectedK[i][selectedK]);
                  $scope.data.push($scope.selectedK[i][selectedK]);

              }
              $scope.datta.push($scope.data);
              console.log($scope.datta);
          }

          function ChartData(){

              $scope.data = [];
              $scope.datta = [];


              console.log($scope.selectedP);
              console.log($scope.selectedItem);
              $scope.dataloaded = true;


              $scope.labels = $scope.selectedP;

              getValue($scope.selectedItem.key);

          }

        },
        controllerAs: "ChartCtrl"
    };
});
```

Is it because maybe my selectedK is not a float?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your number has to be a float if you want to call toFixed method :)

Try this:

```
parseFloat(selectedK[i]).toFixed(2);
```

Hope it helps.